# Why does AngularWebpackPlugin compile my library as CommonJS?

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack, commonjs, umd

I have an Angular 12 library that is published to a local npm repository.
I have a consuming application which uses Webpack 5 to create a module with everything bundled together.
Webpack is targeting ES5 and I have had no issues before.

Snippet of Webpack config:

```
module: {
    rules: [...],
    output: {
      libraryTarget: 'umd'
    },
    plugins: [
      new AngularWebpackPlugin({
        tsconfig: './path/to/tsconfig'
      })
    ],
    target: [es5']
  };
```

Snippet of Tsconfig for webpack:

```
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "es2020",
    "target": "es5",
    "types": ["node"],
    "lib": ["dom", "es2019"]
  },
```

With fresh Webpack builds with fresh modules you normally see output like so (see MyLibrary is compiled as umd):

```
Compiling @angular/core : main as umd
Compiling @angular/common : main as umd
...
Compiling MyLibrary : main as umd
```

A new version was published with only difference being versions of npm dependencies, ***no tsconfig changes***. Now it is giving me this for my library causing errors when the consuming application is trying to use it.

```
Compiling @angular/core : main as umd
Compiling @angular/common : main as umd
...
Compiling MyLibrary : main as commonjs
```

Why does this happen if tsconfig did not change?

How can I force Angular CLI / AngularWebpackPlugin to compile as UMD?

Can the dependencies used really impact the module definition?

Comment: The answer to your last question is yes as far as I know. If your lib uses a non umd import, it might fall back to CJS..

Comment: @MikeOne I was afraid of that.. we use carret on some dependencies and I was worried about having to track down the root node module, is there a way. Do you have a source for this I can read up on?

Comment: Not really, but if you know of a dependency that causes it, you could try to move it from dependencies to peerDependencies - but that only works for first level.. not sure about other solutions I’m afraid.